# Append a whole footer into an HTML page thanks to JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning JS following some tutorials on YouTube, for now my goal is to put some code on the bottom of the page. With a little bit of googling I think what I'm looking for is appending, but I don't find any example of how to append. I found an example of append but it seems like I can append only one element, but since I'm trying to append a whole responsive bootstrap footer, I'll need to append a div with divs in it with classes etc... Is append the right method to use? I can't place the footer in the page itself I only have access to JS that's why I try this way..
I don't know if I should give you the code I want to append, sorry to bother

Answer (score 0):

If you have the whole footer with div children that have classes etc. append will work, and it works as such:

```js
const mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content")
const footerElement = document.createElement("footer")
footerElement.innerHTML = '<footer> other divs with classes etc......</footer>'

mainContent.append(footerElement)
```

Basically, once you have your footer element defined however you need it, you can run the append function on your main content/wherever you want your footer to be at the bottom of, and the element will be added. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering :) It didn't work at first but it kind of worked after some changes. There's still a problem, it does not work with all the code I want to append. It just works for short things like "<p> test </p> but when I copy paste it something bigger it doesn't work. Here's the code
```<script>
window.onload = function() {
const footerElement = document.createElement("footer")
footerElement.innerHTML = '<p>test</p>'

document.body.appendChild(footerElement)
  
}
 </script>```

Comment: @Filou hmm thats weird because it should work. What happens when you try to set the innerHTML to the bootstrap footer?? Can you show me your code and the result?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late update, it works perfectly, when I remove all the tabs from the copy pasted footer. Have a nice day and thanks you for your time :)